# How can I find dart path in intellij idea

Tags: dart

I am stuck .. The intellij idea has said me to paste the path name of dart but I donot know how to know the dart path.. I am very beginner at the dart programming please help me how to find the path of dart that have been installed..

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed through flutter sdk, which also contains the dart sdk, then it will be at C:\Program Files\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk

Answer (score 0):

If you already ran `flutter doctor` you should be able to find the dart SDK in `your_flutter_sdk_folder/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`